# How to pass the file location from "askopenfilename" and use it for a second function

Tags: python, file, tkinter

It is pretty obvious that I'm pretty new to python and I am trying to make a simple GUI with tkinter that would have two buttons. One "Browse" to open file, and for example "Run" to make some operations with this file.

This is the function that I used for File browser, but how to pass this file location to other functions.

```py
def open():
    result = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/C")
    print(result)
```

This is the code so far without any special editing.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()

#root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/C")


def open():
    result = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/C")
    print(result)
    c=result
    return c


theLabel = Label(root, text="The Editor")
theLabel.grid(row=0)

button1 = Button(root, text="Browse", command=open)
button2 = Button(root, text="Run")
button3 = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)

button1.grid(row=1)
button2.grid(row=2)
button3.grid(row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where classes make things a little easier:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.filename = ""

        #root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/C")
        theLabel = Label(self.root, text="The Editor")
        theLabel.grid(row=0)

        button1 = Button(self.root, text="Browse", command=self.open)
        button2 = Button(self.root, text="Run", command=self.other_func)
        button3 = Button(self.root, text="Quit", command=self.root.quit)

        button1.grid(row=1)
        button2.grid(row=2)
        button3.grid(row=3)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def open(self):
        result = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/")
        print("Function open read:")
        print(result)
        self.filename = result
        #print("Set class attribute, calling other function")
        #self.other_func()

    def other_func(self):
        with open(self.filename) as f: # 'with' is preferred for it's error handling
            for c in f:
                print(c)

GUI()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do it with `global` variables as well, but it's bad practice for the most part and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Actualy, there is one small issue. when I add file open and read function inside "other func" file content gets printed out right after i select it in File explorer. I need it to be printed out when I press the second button, not right after it is selected :) any ideas?

Comment: Just remove `self.other_func()` from open, it's calling the other function. I did that just as a demonstration. I edited the code.

Comment: Sorry, got it. Didn't notice that other_func was called inside open function :) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can return the variable:

```
def open():
    result = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    return result

file_path = open()
```

Later you can use `file_path` and pass it to a new function.

You could also immediately call that function from inside the open function while passing `result`:

```
def open():
    result = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    your_function(result)
```

I changed the way you get the file path. I would also advise against naming a function `open()`, since it already is a function in itself:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Well it looks like this function doesn't give only the adress but some other stuff to. So I can't use it just like that. I get this:

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/README.TXT' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: you can `import os` and then use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get the exact path of the file instead

Comment: I have managed to get the location of the selected file with f.name, but how can I pass only this informaton further without calling the entire function. What I mean is, when I press first button I get file explorer and select the file(this is def open()) and if I call this function again I will get the File browser opened again. What I actually need is just the path of the selected file.